# Different UITableViewCell types alignment

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two types of `UITableViewCell` on top of each other. The first one is `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator` and the bottom one is `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone`:

```
if(someCondition)
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}
else
{            
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    // this didn't work
    // cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0, 0.0, 10.0);
}
```

[image]

What I'm trying to do is to move the two labels of the bottom cell to the left , so the right edge of both cells become aligned. I tried to do this by adding a `layoutMargins` to the bottom cell but it didn't work. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the bottom cell's `accessoryView` to an empty view with the needed width.

```
if(someCondition)
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.accessoryView = nil;
}
else
{            
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    // Adjust the width value as needed
    cell.accessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 5)];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Btw, what's the use of `cell.accessoryView = nil;`?

Comment: Cells get reused. You must always set each property for each condition.